# 3D plots in rectangular coordinates

Tags: 3d

How to draw these 3D plots using LaTeX (tikz,pstricks,asympote, ...) :

1. The half sphere `x^2+y^2+z^2=1 | x > 0`
2. `x^2+y^2+z^2=1 | z < -3/5`
3. `x^2+y^2+z^2=1 | 3/5 < z < 1`
4. The dome `x^2+y^2+z^2=1 | z > 0.8`
5. The circle `x^2+y^2+z^2=1 | x=y & -1 <= z <= 1`

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far? If you just want somebody to give you an image, searching the net for a rendering would be the most straightforward. Licence permitting, you can then use `\includegraphics{}` to include the image in your document. This is much easier and much faster than attempting to learn any of the packages you are thinking of using. (I assume you mean TikZ rather than `tik`. If not, I don't know anything about that one.) If you are having trouble with one of these packages and want to use it, please post the code you've got and explain the problem so people can help.

Answer (score 1):

@cfr : It's of course Tikz! Thank you.

For the first one, I've adapted some code found here in SX :

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,intersections, positioning,intersections,shapes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} 

\begin{document}

  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{225}%{60}{110}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
    fill opacity=.5]
    \tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{90}{0}{360}
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{60}{32}%
    {1}{black}{\tdplotphi + 3*\tdplottheta}%
    %{
%     \draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
%       -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
%       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
%         -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
%         {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
%           -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
{\draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};}
{\draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$z$};}
{\draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$x$};}%
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use tikz to draw 2D graphics (in fact, I use geogebra then export the graphics to tikz), but never used it for 3D ones.

I need these graphics for illustration pusposes.

I know a little wxMaxima, gnuplot but can't figure out how to use them to do this.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @Werner : I do not kave (yet) an account!

Comment: @Ufh "Account" means "userid", you have two userid with the same nickname "Ufh". Maybe you've used "sign in" instead of "log in" to enter into the site the second time. See the link in Werner's comment.